# Go package binary reference

Tags: go

I have built a go package (https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful) and I am now trying to reference the output of that package build from my own workspace.

```
$GOPATH
|--src
|  |-- {my source}
|--pkg
|  |-- {package binaries /linux_amd64/github.com/emicklei/go-restful.a}
|--bin
   |-- {my output}
```

but this fails to compile stating can not find package.  go build is only searching the src folder as AFAIK and all the solutions I can find around this involve having the package source code, but surely it's possible to reference package binaries?

Comment: You need *some* kind of source: Just use a dummy source file at the proper path and the proper package declaration and a last modified time earlier than your binary package.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's not possible to reference a package binary, in order to reference a package the  source code is required: http://zduck.com/2014/go-and-package-versioning/

============  EDIT ==============

Turns out you can hack it so that the compiler will use the package output by placing a dummy source file in the expected location with a last modified older than the package output. (see Volker answer to original question).